# Weight paint front and back faces at the same time

Tags: selection-tools, weight-painting, vertex-groups

I want to know how to weight paint the back and front and sides of the selected region at once instead of keep changing the view then doing the same thing. So for example if we have a cube in front view and I pressed the <kbd>B</kbd> to select the bounding box, and I selected the area where the cube is located, what I want to be done is to select everything in this bounding box in all views, so in this case will be the whole cube. 
I have tried enabling and disabling the `limit to selection` option but still only the front faces are selected.

Comment: you could go in to *wireframe* view to use the Border select tool.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like you need to uncheck *limit selection to visible* at the bottom of the 3D view.  When this is selected you can only paint or select geometry that is visible.

[image]

What *limit to selection* does is only let you weight paint geometry which is selected in edit mode.  So be sure that if this is enabled you have gone into edit mode and selected what you want to weight paint.

[image]

Comment: thanks for your reply. I already did that but for some reason when I select the bounding box it still gets only the front faces.

Comment: I have updated the question showing the result

Comment: @user1460166 It's not working because you have faces selected in weight paint mode (the white lines), look in the header and untick a small box with red checkers on it and it should work. Or, if you _do_ need this selection, hold `Ctrl` and select the entire area you want to paint front and back.

Comment: @iKlsR thanks for your comment. I didn't understand what you meant by `look in the header and untick a small box with red checkers on it `. The main thing I want to do is to select all the faces (front,back and sides) when I use the `b` to select them. And then paint them.

Comment: @user1460166 Ok, you have to make the selection in _Edit_ mode, untick the button as shown in the answer and select all the faces, then press Tab and go to object mode and then enter _Weight Paint_ mode and the faces will be selected and you should be able to paint both sides at once. See [this gif](http://giant.gfycat.com/FrequentSecretBarnowl.gif).

Comment: @iKlsR that did the job :D would you post this as an answer so that I choose it?

Comment: @user1460166 This answer is basically _the_ solution, I will edit in the additional bits.

Answer (score 2):

New answer. Applicability:

- Doesn't work with versions prior to 2.8.
- Tested with version 3.1.

---

There are possibly good reasons the options to use are scattered over many places, but this makes Blender unfriendly for common users, even after the ancient exotic UI has been thrown aside. See [Painting through the mesh is not intuitive or user friendly](https://devtalk.blender.org/t/painting-through-the-mesh-is-not-intuitive-or-user-friendly/15231) for a confirmation. Still one can make it work, but there are four elements to adjust according to the result of my experiments:

- Option `Front faces only`
- Falloff `Curve Preset`, `Shape` and `Radius`

Details on where to find them follow.

---

- No need to rush to the usual `Toggle X-Rays` button of the so-called 3D editor header (in common language: The option in the top toolbar of the 3D view). It is used for selection but it plays no role for this painting matter. You may leave it inactive if you wish:

  [image]
- No need either to select the vertices you want to work on, you may have no vertex selected at all if you want. That's my case, and still the brush can paint.
- The first relevant option is found in the toolbar when the 3D view is in Weight-Paint mode and the Draw tool is selected. It's buried in a dropdown list `Brush`, and called `Front faces only`, it must be deselected, it's default state.

  [image]
- Vertices to paint, regardless of whether they are visible or hidden, must be within reach of the brush, as defined by the brush `Radius` found in the toolbar. So be sure to set a value which allows to reach the hidden vertices.

  [image]
- Maybe it's a bug or another exotic area of Blender design, but it seems the falloff mode must be set to '2D'. To do that, in the same toolbar, in the `Falloff` dropdown option panel, set the falloff shape to `Projected`.

  [image]

  And by the way, I've a doubt about the curve preset above, I selected `Sphere` (by default it's `Custom`).

With these settings, painting works on both sides on Blender 3.1:

[image]

We are eight years after your initial question and frankly this way of working looks more like a makeshift job than a standard practice.

Comment: Thanks for this! I was struggling at this so i gave up. This is definitely too many steps for something really simple. imho the steps should've stopped at unchecking "front faces only" option.

Comment: "*This is definitely too many steps for something really simple*", that's the problem with Blender, the perception of simplicity has been always different between developers and fans and mean users. Imho this accounts in the limited use of this otherwise wonderful tool.

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as this 2 steps:

1. **Disable Front Face Only in brush setting** (so that you will paint the backface also)
2. **Change Fall Off type to Projected.** (so that your brush will project straight through the 3d object, hitting the backface)

Enjoy.